# Codeigniter - routes multiple parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I want to show single blog news by slug but I do not know

Blog Controller :

```html
        public function show_news($slug)
        {
          $page_data['page_title']  = 'News';
          $page_data['news_item'] = $this->blog_model->get_news($slug);

          $this->template->load('frontend/blog_news',$page_data);

        }
```

Blog Model :

```html
  function get_news($slug)
    {
      $slugs = urldecode($slug);
       $query = $this->db->get_where('blogposts', array('slug' => $slugs));
if($query->num_rows() > 0 ){
 if($this->db->get_Where('blogposts', array('slug'=>$slugs))->row()->status == '1'){
  return $query->row_array();
     }
  }
    }
```

my route :

```html
$route['blog/(:any)/news/(:any)'] = "blog/show_news/$1/$2";
```

Comment: your question in incomplete, explain more

Comment: @MahdiMajidzadeh in view data not show anything , where is my wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have only one parameter(`$slug`) with `show_news` function so obviously  the route `"blog/show_news/$1/$2";` will be incorrect.Manage your route like this..

```
$route['blog/news/(:any)'] = "blog/show_news/$1";
```

It redirects every `blog/show_news/slug` to `blog/news/slug`

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you have only 1 parameter. This is not ok with your route configuration. It should be
`$route['blog/news/(:any)'] = "blog/show_news/$1";` as already said.

But, your question title is

> Codeigniter - routes ***multiple parameters***

If you mean that you want to pass another parameter, than, with your current route, you can access the $2 variable by adding a second parameter to the method of your controller like this.

```
public function show_news($slug, $secondParameter){
```